# c++ how to use inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes BaseJob and DerivedJob and then I have some code working with it:

```
Beanstalkpp::BaseJob* Beanstalkpp::Client::reserve() {

  if (something)
  {
      return new ExtendedJob(some_data);
  }
  if (something_else)
  {
      return new SpecialJob(some_data);
  }
}
```

I would like to use it like:

```
ExtendedJob *j = client.reserve()
```

But so far I am getting:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘Beanstalkpp::BaseJob*’ to ‘Beanstalkpp::ExtendedJob*’ [-fpermissive]
```

**Update:**

```
class BaseJob 
{
  ...
}

class ExtendedJob : public BaseJob
{
  ...
}
```

**Update 2**:
So because a lot of answers says that it is not possible, or if it is, then by doing something dangerous I would like to more describe what I try to resolve.

I have some basic functions for work with jobs like:

```
BaseJob reserve()
void del(BaseJob& j)
void bury(BaseJob& j)
...
```

And then I have some Job clases like ExtendedJob, SpecialJob which all extends BaseJob. All function mentioned above will do same (will call same function calls on objects).

So I see 2 ways of solving my problem

- For each job type I will create custom function like reserveBaseJob(), reserveSpecialJob() ...
- For each function i will create same function but as template and then each call of function will contain class name like: del()

All jobs classes implement same interface....

Comment: What's the inheritance hierarchy? Where do templates come in?

Comment: @FredLarson sorry I removed templates and added hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because you can never be sure that your `client.reserve()` creates `ExtendedJob`, not `SpecialJob` or whatever else. Consider how you code would run if `reserve()` creates `SpecialJob` or `SomeOtherUnrelatedJob`, but you try to save it to a pointer to `ExtendedJob`?

If you are sure that `reserve()` will *always* create `ExtendedJob` or its subclasses wherever it is called from, then change its declaration to return `ExtendedJob*`.

If you are sure that `reserve()` will *always* create `ExtendedJob` or its subclasses when it is called from that particular place, then you may use `dynamic_cast`, but anyway this smells of bad design.

Comment: So basically what I have  to do is create functions like reserveExtendedJob(), reserverSpecialJob(), reserveSomeOtherJob(),... and so on right?

Comment: @DusanPlavak, this I can't say, because this heavily depends on your architecture. Anyway a bunch of such function does not seem proper. Maybe it will be a templated function, or you will change your design and avoid it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are implicitly converting a base class type to the derived class type. Use `dynamic_cast<T>` for that.

```
ExtendedJob *j = dynamic_cast<ExtendedJob*>(client.reserve());
```

This will yield `NULL` if the cast cannot be performed, e.g., because the pointer is of another type hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that the return type of the function is `Beanstalkpp::BaseJob*`. So, when you return `ExtendedJob*`, it is implicitly casted up to `BaseJob*`.

Then, in your program code you want to downcast to `ExtendedJob*` from the base pointer, which is dangerous, because it can also be `SpecialJob*`. If you expect that the pointer will be `ExtendedJob*`, you can try explicit cast with great care:

```
ExtendedJob* j = dynamic_cast<Beanstalkpp::ExtendedJob*>(client.reserve());
if (NULL != j) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is possible, I'd suggest to make it like this:

```
BaseJob* j = client.reserve();
```

and include into BaseJob some virtual methods that overridden by ExtendedJob.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `BaseJob` is the base class for `ExtendedJob` and `SpecialJob`, you should do:

```
BaseJob * j = client.reserve();
```

The error you're getting means you're trying to convert `BaseJob` (the return type of `reserve()`) to one of its childs. The compiler cannot be sure of this, so it throws an error. A `dynamic_cast<ExtendedJob*>` will force this convertion, but it's usually not a good design.

Answer (score 0):

Derived-to-base class conversions are possible. But this conversion i.e, derived-to-base-class conversion is not seen in your code. The problem you're facing is that you made a pointer of derived class point to its base class here:

```
ExtendedJob *j = client.reserve()
```

The problem is that `ExtendedJob` will point to its part (i.e, `ExtendedJob`'s members) of `BaseJob` object. But there are no such members and hence the compiler flags an error.

The **fix** is to use ***dynamic_cast***:

```
ExtendedJob *j = dynamic_cast<ExtendedJob*>(client.reserve())
```